# How to add 'AND' parts to Joomla Jdatabase query?

Tags: mysql, joomla

I need to write an db query based on the Joomla jdatabase format, but I get stuck with writing the 2 'AND' parts for the native sql query below (I could not figure it out based on http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase).

How to include the 2 AND parts? Appreciate your help

```
//get userid of collective based on entered collective name, and get productid based on    entered productname

//NATIVE MYSQL: 

SELECT #__users.id, #__products.productid
FROM #__users INNER JOIN #__products
ON #__users.id = #__products.owner
AND #__users.name = $form_username
AND #__products.productname  = $form_productname;
```

What I have sofar:

```
//Joomla Jdatabase query sofar:

$query
->select($db->quoteName(array('a.id', 'b.productid')))
->from($db->quoteName('#__users', 'a'))
->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__products', 'b') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('a.id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('b.owner') . ') ') //HERE I think some AND parts need to be included in some way?
 ->order($db->quoteName('a.created') . ' DESC');
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this so please let me know if it works and if not, I will come back with an edit

```
->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__products', 'b') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('a.id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('b.owner') . ') 
AND ' . $db->quoteName('#__users.name') . ' = ' . $form_username . ' 
AND ' . $db->quoteName('#__products.productname') . ' = ' . $form_productname)
```

Comment: thnx! i will test it tomorrow and let you know

Comment: Hi, sorry, my reaction a bit later through private circumstance: it didnt work; i get the error message "1054 - Unknown column 'weq_users.name' in 'on clause' SQL=SELECT `a`.`id`,`b`.`productid` FROM `weq_users` AS `a` INNER JOIN `weq_products` AS `b` ON (`a`.`id` = `b`.`owner`) AND `weq_users`.`name` = 'green' AND `weq_products`.`productname` = 'testwindfarm'"